# Changes to twitter API

Tags: twitter

Just looking for some clarity on the new Twitter API changes coming in if anyone could help out please-

Do the API changes affect how I go about placing for e.g. the top 5 tweets from my timeline onto my site. I've used some quick javascript techniques before to do this but does the new authentication mean I have to go through PHP Oauth or similar in order to do the same thing? Would it break previous setups I have done before?

I've used this code before:
http://pastebin.com/hFZhfavk
And then just your username in here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/USERNAME.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=2"></script>
```

Had a look through some of the documentation on the changes but not sure if its just for application stuff or if it affects the likes of what I'm doing aswell.

All help much appreciated! And if anyone could point me in the direction of some good tutorials/info if the set up is different that'd be great too.

Thanks for your time

/* ed */
I've since set up Twitter Oauth in PHP using @abraham's setup. Everytime I load the test page I get asked to sign into Twitter - is that the way twitter feeds are gonna have to be on sites now with the new rules? Still a little confused if anyone has any insight it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but the answer is yes - all Twitter API 1.1 calls have to be authenticated. API 1.0 has been switched off permanently. |

This should explain all: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired